# Rescheduling Service Activities

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2013

We have people reschedule services activities all the time using the following form:

[image]

The main problem we are encountering is when rescheduling a two hour slot the duration defaults to 1.

Is there a way to insert a javascript file into this form so that we can set the duration to be the same as the original booking as our end users are having problems?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no supported way to implement your requirement. The best alternative would be to register a plugin on the `Reschedule` message of a `Appointment` entity to force the scheduled end time on the original activity to be `n minutes` after the original duration.